# ¿Qué etiqueta seria la mas apropiada utilizar para añadir un botón que registre suscriptores?

Tags: css

he creado la siguiente página web y deseo añadir un botón, en la parte del formulario que registre las visitas y me lo envíe a mi otra página web ¿Qué etiqueta debo utilizar?

```css
<html>
<head>
<title> Pagina web
</title>
</head>
<body>


<p>Formulario De Suscripción:</p>
<form class="formulario2" method="post">
 Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre"> </br>
 DNI: <input type="text" name="DNI"> </br>
 Email: <input type="email" name="email"> </br>
 <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: por favor, defínenos etiqueta, esta es la parte que me confunde.

Comment: lo digo porque veo tu codigo muy bien

Comment: cual es el problema?

Comment: preguntaba sobre la etiqueta que debo añadir para que los datos almacenados en el formulario sean enviados a mi otra página web

Comment: Sigue las instrucciones de este foro. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379238/send-email-with-php-from-html-form-on-submit-with-the-same-script/18382062 Espero que te ayude.
Un saludo!

Comment: @pablo, la pregunta no será ¿cual es el atributo que le falta a mi formulario para que los datos se envíen a otra página web? Si es así, [`action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/form#Atributos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la linea de codigo

```
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
```

Debe de ser asi

```
<input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Enviar">
```

Para que por metodo POST puedas enviar los datos.

Te dejo este ejemplo de script para el envio del correo espero que te sirva

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Enviar'])) {

// Debes editar las próximas dos líneas de código de acuerdo con tus preferencias
$email_to = "destinatario@sudominio.com";
$email_subject = "Contacto desde el sitio web";

// Aquí se deberían validar los datos ingresados por el usuario
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
!isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
!isset($_POST['email']) ||
!isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
!isset($_POST['comments'])) {

echo "<b>Ocurrió un error y el formulario no ha sido enviado. </b><br />";
echo "Por favor, vuelva atrás y verifique la información ingresada<br />";
die();
}

$email_message = "Detalles del formulario de contacto:\n\n";
$email_message .= "Nombre: " . $_POST['first_name'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Apellido: " . $_POST['last_name'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "E-mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Teléfono: " . $_POST['telephone'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Comentarios: " . $_POST['comments'] . "\n\n";


// Ahora se envía el e-mail usando la función mail() de PHP
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

echo "¡El formulario se ha enviado con éxito!";
}
?>
```